# Multi-GPU training of Grover's model

Tags: python, tensorflow, training-data, gpu

I am trying to train [Grover's](https://github.com/rowanz/grover) discriminator model on multiple GPUs with tensorflow==1.13.1. Default configuration of the model assumes training over multiple TPUs and is proven to work on systems with multiple TPUs. However because of unavailability of TPUs, I am trying to distribute training over multiple GPUs by changing model's running configuration using tensorflow distribution strategy as follows:

```
dist_strategy = tf.contrib.distribute.MirroredStrategy(
        num_gpus=8,
        cross_device_ops=AllReduceCrossDeviceOps('nccl', num_packs=8),
        # cross_device_ops=AllReduceCrossDeviceOps('hierarchical_copy')
)
```

Then I tried changing running configuration for GPUs as follows:

```
 run_config = RunConfig(
        train_distribute=dist_strategy,
        eval_distribute=dist_strategy,
        log_step_count_steps=log_every_n_steps,
        model_dir=FLAGS.output_dir,
        save_checkpoints_steps=FLAGS.iterations_per_loop)
```

It seems to distribute data correctly (I can tell by GPU usage and other metrics) but upon collection of gradients it fails with following error:

```
ValueError: You must specify an aggregation method to update a MirroredVariable in Replica Context.
```

[image]

However, I have provided cross-device operation in distribution strategy. To me it seems that ultimate solution is to modify loss function with distribution strategy code but I think it should work as it works with TPUs. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue and train on multi-gpu? Also interested in how to fix this.

Comment: No I wasnt able to fix it. Neither could find an alternate optimal solution